# templated operator overloading cannot bind non-const lvalue reference

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend

I have tried variations of const and passing by reference, but seem to have problems down every corridor.
This configuration gives the error cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘thingArr&’ to an rvalue of type ‘thingArr’
what am I doing incorrectly?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class thingArr
{
public:
  thingArr(){for(int i=0;i<4;++i)n[i] = 1;}
  thingArr(thingArr& mIn){for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)n[i]=mIn.n[i];}
  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& s, thingArr<T>& m)
  {
    s<<"\n("<<m.n[0]<<", "<<m.n[1]<<", "<<m.n[2]<<", "<<m.n[3]<<")";
    return s;
  }
  friend thingArr operator * (thingArr inThingArr, T inScalar)
  {
    thingArr out(inThingArr);
    for(int i=0;i<4;++i)out.n[i]*=inScalar;
    return thingArr(out);
  }

  T n[4];
};

main(){
  thingArr<float> A;
  thingArr<float> B;
  B = A * .25;
  cout <<"A: "<<A<<endl;
  cout <<"B: "<<B<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Why not `const thingArr& mIn` in args?

Comment: that gives the error "binding reference of type ‘thingArr<float>&’ to ‘const thingArr<float>’ discards qualifiers" on line 16

Comment: Where `const thingArr<float>` comes from? I don't see it in your code. And just `return out`.

Comment: ah! ok, a lead. thank you S.M. ! this seems to work:

```
class thingArr
{
public:
  thingArr(){for(int i=0;i<4;++i)n[i] = 1;}
  thingArr(const thingArr& mIn){for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)n[i]=mIn.n[i];}
  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& s, thingArr<T>& m)
  {
 s<<"\n("<<m.n[0]<<", "<<m.n[1]<<", "<<m.n[2]<<", "<<m.n[3]<<")";
 return s;
  }
  friend thingArr operator * (const thingArr& inThingArr, T inScalar)
  {
 thingArr out(inThingArr);
 for(int i=0;i<4;++i)out.n[i]*=inScalar;
 return thingArr(out);
  }

  T n[4];
};
```

Comment: Why not `const thingArr<T>& m` in args?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to S.M., I have a working version:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class thingArr
{
public:
  thingArr(){for(int i=0;i<4;++i)n[i] = 1;}
  thingArr(const thingArr& mIn){for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)n[i]=mIn.n[i];}
  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& s, thingArr<T>& m)
  {
    s<<"\n("<<m.n[0]<<", "<<m.n[1]<<", "<<m.n[2]<<", "<<m.n[3]<<")";
    return s;
  }
  friend thingArr operator * (const thingArr& inThingArr, T inScalar)
  {
    thingArr out(inThingArr);
    for(int i=0;i<4;++i)out.n[i]*=inScalar;
    return thingArr(out);
  }

  T n[4];
};

main(){
  thingArr<float> A;
  thingArr<float> B;
  B = A * .25;
  cout <<"A: "<<A<<endl;
  cout <<"B: "<<B<<endl;
}
```

Comment: And `std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& s, const thingArr<T>& m)`, you don't modify `m`to display it.